# How to prevent the application redirects the background application when click on a certain button in the user interface

Tags: ms-word, vb6

I am maintaining an Add In to Microsoft office word application using VB6.

There is a main dialog and a sub dialog. The Main dialog is loading after clicking on a button in the MS Word Ribbon bar. The sub dialog is loading with a button click on the main dialog.

When user clicks on the button in the sub dialog, and then click on the OK button of the main dialog, the application (MS word document) redirects to the background. Background means not  the desktop of the machine,  but any other application like google chrome or visual studio that is not minimized and used recently. But when the user skips the certain button in the main dialog and click on the OK button that redirection issue is not happening.

I have to prevent that redirecting. I have debug the code and tried to find a solution. There is not any relationship with MS Word and the other background application.

Anybody have an idea about the reason of this issue. Please help me.

Comment: What's the difference in code between the two scenarios?

Comment: You don't provide enough information for people to even begin to guess what may be happening....